# Various Small capacitors' markings?

Tags: capacitor, markings

*Wikipedia explains the basics about the markings of capacitors, [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Capacitor_markings) It lacks many markings most of which confuses me:*

**Ceramic brown-yellowish cap**

- 104 K5K (small )   --- what is the end "5K"? (Cannot be 5 kelvin as operating temperature!?)
- 10 (box box, perpendicular right upermost corner) 35+  (Tantalum Cap, bigger variant of the last one
- 154 C1K  (what is C1K, some other notation to Wikipedia?)

**Orange Ceramic**

- 333 K5X   (what is 5X? X roman numeral?)

**Brown Circle Slit**

- 10n (no other marking, what is the op.temp?) (Diameter: 7.5mm)
- 27J 100V (what is 27J?) (Diameter: 4.9mm, blackdot on the head)

**Blue Slit Square**

- (triangle) 104K X7R50   (What is triangle? X7R50? Operating V?) (side = 4.9mm)
- 104   (side = 2.6mm, op.V? Tolerance?)

**Questions about the bracketed**

1. How to know operating V without its explicit marking?
2. What do the symbols, such as squares, plus-sign and triangle, mean?
3. Can you evaluate the operating voltage from the size of the capacitor in the case when no marking or poor marking is given?

Comment: Related question (*maybe* this can be considered a duplicate): http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16636/ceramic-capacitors-how-to-read-values

Answer (score 9):

**Generally there are two labels on most caps.**

The first is the value, which is written:
`<Digit><Digit><Exponential Notation>`
It's generally in picofarads.

The second is the TempCo, or Temperature Coefficient. There are two common specification systems, namely [EIA Class 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIA_Class_1_dielectric) and [Class 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIA_Class_2_dielectric). This is the mysterious second label in most cases. It's generally written:
`<Letter><Number><Letter>` (though there are a few variations)
There are a few common tempcos - NP0/C0G, X7R, X5R, Y5V, Z5U

Tantalums, and bigger ceramics often also have the voltages:
`<voltage number><+ or v>`

Therefore:

- 104 K5K (small )
  The value is 10e4, or 100,000 pf / 0.1 uF. The tempco is not standard, may be manufacturer specific/extended range.
- 10 (box box, perpendicular right upermost corner) 35+ (Tantalum Cap, bigger variant of the last one)
  Need a picture to be more specific, it's very likely a 35v rated cap, from the 35+.
- 154 C1K (what is C1K, some other notation to Wikipedia?)
  Capacitance is 15e4, or 150,000 pf / 0.15 uF. Looks to be a Class 1 dielectric from the C1K. Is this a large cap? the tempco is *very* good.
- Orange Ceramic 333 K5X (what is 5X? X roman numeral?)
  33e3, or 33,000 pf / 33 nF. Tempco is either manufacturer specific, or incorrectly read.
- Brown Circle Slit 10n (no other marking, what is the op.temp?) (Diameter: 7.5mm)
  10n very likely means 10 nf, or 10,000 pf. If it's ceramic, it's *probably* 50v. Likely a cheap part, if the voltage is not marked.
- 27J 100V (what is 27J?) (Diameter: 4.9mm, blackdot on the head)
  Voltage rating is self evident. J is the multiplier, and I *think* there is a standard for letter multipliers, but I do not remember where to find it.
- Blue Slit Square (triangle) 104K X7R50 (What is triangle? X7R50? Operating V?) (side = 4.9mm)
  10e4 is the value - 100,000 pf / 0.1uF Tempco is X7R. the 50 is likely the voltage rating.
- 104 (side = 2.6mm, op.V? Tolerance?)
  10e4 - 100,000 pf / 0.1uF. Voltage is not known

This is kind of a guess. Anyways, it should show how this sort of thing works. Older parts may vary wildly, and it's always just a guideline. The best thing to do is find the cap's actual datasheet.

A lot of the parts have unusual tempcos. Is this a automotive/extreme duty part which contains these components?

Answer (score 4):

The "K5K", "K5X", "C1K" that doesn't match a temperature characteristic (X7R, NPO, C0G, etc.) is a manufacturer-dependent part marking to make use of the limited space available on the part.

If you look at some of the major manufacturers' datasheets for radial-lead ceramic capacitors, you'll see the following. Capacitance tolerance codes seem to be consistent, but otherwise there is some disparity.

- [Murata](http://www.murata.com/products/capacitor/catalog/index.html):

  - First character = capacitance tolerance (C = +/-0.25pF, D = +/-0.5pF, J = +/-5%, K = +/-10%, M = +/-20%, Z = +80%/-20%)
  - Second character = voltage rating (2 = 25VDC, 5 = 50VDC, 1 = 100VDC, 4 = 250VDC, 9 = 450VDC, 7 = 630VDC)
  - Third character = temperature characteristics (A = C0G, C = X7S/X7R, F = F/F5V, 8 = X8G/X8L, 7 = X7T)
- [AVX](http://www.avx.com/prodinfo_catalogview.asp?prxID=37&iPageNum=1):

  - First character = temperature characteristics (A = C0G, C = X7R, D = X5R, E = Z5U, F = X8R, )
  - Second character = voltage rating (Z = 10VDC, 5 = 50VDC, 1 = 100VDC, 2 = 200VDC, 9 = 300VDC, 8 = 400VDC, 7 = 500VDC)
  - Third character = capacitance tolerance (C = +/-0.25pF, D = +/-0.5pF, F = +/- 1%, G = +/-2%, J = +/-5%, K = +/-10%, M = +/-20%, Z = +80%/-20%)
- [KEMET](http://www.kemet.com/kemet/web/homepage/kechome.nsf/Weben/Ceramic%20Capacitors#thr-cer): unclear, first character is sometimes a "K" for KEMET; they use the same capacitance tolerance codes as AVX, but seem to mark with the full text of the voltage rating and temperature characteristics where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a staring [point](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/electronic-components-the-capacitor/). If you know the type of capacitor that you have, but not what the value is, have a look at (for example) Farnell website and search for that part type. Then you can get a data sheet which usually explains things nicely.

Comment: Could you please post real links!

Answer (score 0):

**2. About "+"-sign**

The plus means "polarised", the source is [tronixstuff's site, point "Tantalum capacitors"](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/electronic-components-the-capacitor).

[More here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/what-does-polarization-mean-in-polarized-cap)

Comment: Why did you not take the time to just comment on his. This is something you got because of his answer, he should be rewarded.

Comment: Kortuk: Yes and I am not taking credit of it, please, see the "the source is --". I think it is better to consider each point separately well in an answer rather than tell everything you know on a one big answer. Anyway, it is not identical it evolved to a next question which I think is now much easier to read than reading jammed comments.

Comment: Kortuk: cannot see a reason why you're pointing these things? There are still many points answered in 1-3. I will attack them soonish if there is no-one else to attack them. I call it self-learning and I think it is a good thing. Tronixstuff's article is just an introduction and did not cover all of points in the question.