# Capacitor values

Tags: capacitor, component-values

I don't have high-end multimeter. So, anybody please tell me the values of the following capacitors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah. Googling helps. Also, so does at least [tolerable photographing](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7232/64158).

Comment: I tried, but I was really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing some googling:

1. https://www.datasheets360.com/part/detail/mdd-p2g104k/-3413801210437993611/

0.1 uF

2. See [Ceramic capacitors: how to read 2-digit markings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18102/ceramic-capacitors-how-to-read-2-digit-markings)

47 or 4.7 pF (I cannot see clearly if there is a dot).

3. See 2.

22 pF

Comment: Thankyou. one doubt, is last 2 type of capacitors are always in pF range. 1 can see the values but confused between nF and pF.

Comment: @Vishal As far as I know, ceramic capacitors are always in pF. See the accepted answer to the link in item 2.

Comment: Ooh, I got my answer in the above attached answer. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Hm, you can get MLCC at least for 22 µF, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But than it would be written as u47 or 4u7 right?

Comment: Agree - For capacitors, given lack of an explicit multiplier, 'picofarads' is presumed.    So 2nd and 3rd caps are 47 and 22 pF for sure.

Comment: @KyleB Thanks for the confirmation