# What is this capacitor marked F 103?

Tags: capacitor, identification

I am trying to learn how to identify old capacitors I have. I haven't been able to crack the search "code". I tried testing with my MESR100 ESR meter with no luck. Just says OL. Help finding a site where I can research better would help.

Pictured is my latest conundrum:

[image]

[image: capacitor]

Comment: The existing [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16637/101063) in [Ceramic capacitors: how to read 3-digit plus 1-letter markings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16636/ceramic-capacitors-how-to-read-3-digit-plus-1-letter-markings) suggests this would be a 10 nF capacitor (the ``103`` marking) with a +/1 % tolerance (the ``F`` marking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are 10nF ceramic disk capacitors.

The 3 is the multiplier.  The 10 is the value in picofarads.

That's 10 picofarads multiplied by 1000 (three zeroes.) That's 10000 picofarads, which is also called 10 nanofarads.

That's a pretty standard way of marking ceramic disk capacitors.  If it were just two digits then the value would be picofarads only.  [Have a look here for a longer description.](https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/capacitor-value-code-calculator)

Answer (score 1):

Why focus on the capacitor marking when there's a manufacturer (TDK) part number on the bag?

The capacitor is from the CK45 series - per the first letters of the part number.

Datasheet:

https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/capacitor/ceramic/lead-disc/catalog/leaddisc_commercial_ck45_en.pdf

Comment: Except that the interesting parts "YV1E" which would give the temperature rating and  voltage rating aren't explained in that document.

Comment: The markings show in the datasheet don't match the ``F`` ``103`` shown on the capacitors . E.g. all the example markings in the datasheet show the rated voltage (the CK45 series are rated as either 1 kV DC , 2 kV DC or 3 kV DC voltage). Perhaps, for confusion, someone placed some different capacitors in some random other TDK labeled bag.

Comment: I have 23 bags or 23000 of these so I believe they are labeled correctly. I just don't understand how to figure these out. How do I find voltage if they aren't marked?

Comment: @MikeA, dimension of the caps might give you some clue. This seems to be some 30-years-old cap. You might be better if you contact TDK directly. However, for high-voltage  parts that old, no one will risk their design and buy these parts.  The best way is probably just recycle all bags.